# "The Resource Cannot Be Found: /Login.aspx" on new v5.20 Install

Tags: iis-7, windows-7, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

Please see my [DNN Forum Post](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/107/threadid/343877/scope/posts/Default.aspx) for more details.

I've never had any issues with DotNetNuke installations. But with the new v5.20 (or v5.02, whichever it really is), everything runs perfectly fine through installation. I then get to the main default portal homepage. But as soon as I click any of the links available to continue (Home, Register or Login) I get 404 errors every time with a reference back to the applicable aspx page (Home.aspx, Register.aspx or Login.aspx.).

Windows 7, IIS7, SQL Server 2008. All permissions are setup properly on the directory and in IIS. I would think this is an IIS7 configuration issue, but I've tweaked everything in there a half-dozen times. No one at DNN is returning answers on my forum post anymore either after one guy tried.

Help!

Comment: No offense but after that comment at the bottom of the second page not surprised no one else wanted to help - anyway onwards and upwards

Comment: Non taken sir. Though I must say I was speaking directly to the guy named Sebastian. He asked me the same questions more than once when I'd already answered him more than once. Then he continued to accuse those issues of still being the problem, therefore basically saying I'm an idiot. Instead of suggestions, the DNN team should duplicate the environment and figure out why so may folks on various versions have had the same problems. I felt fully justified in what I said to him and was gracious to any and all others who may attempt to help. I was clear & concise; not sure what else I could do.

Comment: Was your web.config read-only during install by chance?  The login url gets re-written, sounds like their handlers and modules aren't setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is something to do with the Friendly URL stuff.  I found [this](http://www.blog.shancer.com/post/Configuring-DotNetNuke-to-Produce-a-Human-Friendly-URL.aspx) blog post which talks about the Friendly URL Provider architecture.  This made me try changing the urlFormat attribute for the DNNFriendlyUrl provider from "humanfriendly" to "searchfriendly", which made the URLs the way they used to be.  I'm not sure exactly where things are going wrong and don't really have time to dig into it at the moment, but hopefully this will be helpful to get you moving again too.

Comment: That was the first place I looked after installing the new v5.x version. But I wasn't able to get anywhere with it. Thanx for the blog post, but none of those options make it work. I have to change the port on the IIS app to 80 to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of DNN5 (up until 5.02.01 as of the time of writing), the friendly URL provider won't work when DotNetNuke is not on default port 80. There are different solutions floating around, but the simplest is just to replace the DNN friendly URL provider with the free one from iFinity. The installation is really simple and included in the download. Or see the following blog post:

http://www.sailer.com.au/dotnetnuke/dnn5-friendlyurl-port

Answer (score 0):

Okay have you tried the 'old style' of login - **domain.com/default.aspx?ctl=login**

If that still doesnt work then i have to say that most likely something has happened to IIS - if so then you might just see if you can install the package you have on a different box or have a friend try a different box

I have done 2 upgrades with 5.2 and a few test installs with the Starter Kit Package and Install packages and have never seen this problem - not to say that it doesnt exist.

My next trial would be to go and redownload the install package from CodePlex and start from scratch to see if you can make the same thing happen again.

Comment: Answering from the bottom:

- The first thing I did was completely exhaust my own efforts before posting to the DNN forum. By then I'd already installed from scratch no less than 6 times.

- I'm very pleased to hear it worked for you. I however had the same results described above from both the Web Platform Installer and the individual items from CodePlex.

- Old style login you suggested worked! I knew nothing was wrong with IIS. But still can't get further. From the beginning I've suspected the new Friendly URL provider as it's a new element in the config file. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OKayone thing I dont think that has been mentioned in reading through everything is double check IIS.

My first guess without looking on your server would be to check if something happened to the 'check file exists' setting - i know this is changed in IIS7 so I cant point to the exact place to check this.

Here is a link to the IIS7 forums on it - http://forums.iis.net/t/1092696.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1191083.aspx
either one might help - google also has a lot on this

Tell me how this goes in checking up on it and we can move forward from there!

Comment: Ok: Under "Request Filtering" in IIS7 are lots of default filetypes that are all listed as "False" already. I messed around with all commmon types as well and still got nowhere. If I added aspx as false, I couldn't get to the main portal page any longer.

Since I can get to the pages using the old style, it seems there's something in IIS that could be tweaked yet. I'm all ears for suggestions sir.

Comment: have you tried on a second box or fresh install at all - i am convinced there is something wrong on the box/install you are using but its going to be hard to pinpoint it

Comment: This is the only Windows 7 box I have unfortunately. So that's not an option.

I had breakthrough last night. Per another post to my DNN Forum thread, it has to do with the port somehow. If I place it under Port 80, everything works great! But under any other port it breaks as I've stated. I found a "UsePortNumber" app setting in the config and played around with it, but no luck. If I set that value to "false", the site just goes to the default IIS7 homepage on my local box instead of starting up the portal. More thoughts?

Comment: are you doing https on the site? or is it required in iis - i assume not but its a good thing to get out of the way

Comment: Nope. Just your standard vanilla site. Please keep in mind: I scrapped everything I had previously because of problems and just started back with a brand new install. I used the new database & everything. Pretend I'm a DNN n00b. Everything was raw from Install, IIS was a simple app hooked to the physical location of files. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to reg_iis on the version(s) of asp.net that your IIS is going to support.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx

If the right version is not set up then you will get the 404 error

Comment: No, this isn't it. Everything runs fine and ran fine before moving from v4.x to v5.x. It appears to be some issue with friendly URL's and/or port assignments.

Answer (score 0):

So placing it under port 80 works, right?
Is there a good reason not putting it under that port?

Comment: Yep. That's the only way I could get it to work. KUDOS to a guy named Jeff Dyck that answered my forum post listed above.

I just prefer clear separation in my web apps working locally. It also keeps me from having to change the default site port around just to use 80 elsewhere. However, the answer is yet to be found as to what changed in the new version that's preventing me from using other ports and how to configure it in IIS7. Maybe it's just that the folks at DNN that know how to fix this haven't seen or heard about the post yet.